# How to align text in HaxeFlixel?

Tags: text, haxe, text-alignment, haxeflixel

I have a `FlxText` object which has properties like:

```haxe
var CharHP:FlxText = new FlxText(1000, 500);
CharHP.Text = "HP: " + "9999";
CharHP.width = 300; CharHP.height = 200;
CharHP.alignment = "center";
```

I'm trying to align `CharHP` to center and I expect these coordinates:

`1000+(300/2), 500+(200/2)`

However, the text is at:

`1000, 500`

Answer (score 2):

Text alignment centers the *visual display* of the text itself rather than the text box itself. The text box itself will always be "at" the x/y you supply in the constructor or by setting x and y directly.

Example:

```
[Left aligned text        ]
[       Right aligned text]
[   Center aligned text   ]
```

In all three cases the coordinates and size of the text box itself are the same, but the visual position of the text itself is different.

Comment: You just wrote [   Center aligned text   ]. How can I set width between[ and ] ?

Comment: @EnesF. You have to give the third argument to the FlxText constructor which is a FieldWidth, ex: FlxText(1000, 500, 300).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Not sure why I don't have to import FlxTextAlign to get this working but feel free to refer to the API docs for more info.
https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/text/FlxTextAlign.html

```js
import flixel.text.FlxText;

...

var text = new FlxText( 300, "Your text to center", 24); // the field width argument is important
text.alignment = FlxTextAlign.CENTER; // This can be LEFT, RIGHT, JUSTIFY
```